Google requires a reason for host permission for my plugin, but I didn't ask for any permission at all
I wrote a plugin for Chrome. The extension activates JS that changes pages on a certain site, immediately upon loading and without the need to click on the extension.
There is no jumper.
I didn't write any permission in the manifest, and I checked - it works fine in 'development mode'.
What's weird is that when I uploaded the extension to my developer account in the chrome extension store, I was asked to explain why I needed host permission. It is also written there, that due to this permission, the plug-in test will be delayed.
The questions:

Why is this happening?
What can be done?
Is Google "unintentionally right", and my plugin won't work without the permission?

Attach the manifest code:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Random Content Injector",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Injects a random content menu into XXXXXXXXXX",
  "icons": {
    "16": "open_book_icon_16x16.png",
    "48": "open_book_icon_48x48.png",
    "128": "open_book_icon_128x128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://XXXXXXXXXX/*"],
      "js": [
        "js/jquery-3.6.0.js",
    "js/content.js"      ]
    }
  ]
}

